# Why aren't these logically equivalent? How can I show this?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

i. (∃x)(∀y)Fxy

ii. (∀y)(∃x)Fxy

I am supposed to show that these are not logically equivalent by giving an interpretation that makes one true and the other false. I have the intuition that I need a two element universe of discourse, but I'm not sure how to write this out. Thank all for any help!

Comment: Putting "there exists" before "for every" gives very different statements than going the other way around. Consider the definitions of limits, continuity, etc. in which we fix an $\varepsilon$ up front, then find a $\delta$. This is not the same as going like: "there exists $\varepsilon$ such that for all $\delta$..."

Comment: Is it a logic class, or a general math class?

Comment: This is a Symbolic Logic 400 level undergraduate course. I have never taken a logic course in my life so this is seriously throwing me for a loop.

Comment: Statement (i) implies statement (ii), but (ii) does not imply (i).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following formula over the set of natural numbers:
$$F(x,y) \equiv (x>y).$$
Then $\forall y\exists x F(x,y)$ holds, but $\exists x\forall y F(x,y)$ fails.

We can in fact give an interpretation of finite domain which shows these two formulas are not equivalent. The idea is to consider a direct graph and mimicking my previous example. Here is a concrete description: let $D =\{0,1,2\}$ and $F=\{(0,1),\,(1,2),\,(2,0)\}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\exists x~\forall y~F(x,y)$ versus $\forall y~\exists x~F(x,y)$

Imagine $F(x,y)$ to say: there is mail in row $x$ and column $y$ of the square pigeon-hole board.

Then $\exists x~\forall y~F(x,y)$ says there some row with mail in every column.    The mail that makes this true has to line up in the same row.

While $\forall y~\exists x~F(x,y)$ says in every column there is mail in some row.   The mail that makes this true does not have to be in the same row.

---

> I have the intuition that I need a two element universe of discourse, but I'm not sure how to write this out.

Consider the universe $\{0,1\}$ and relation $F$ that makes 
$\exists x\forall y~F(x,y)$ false, but $\forall y~\exists x~F(x,y)$ true.

Ie: Put mail in every column but not the same row...$$\begin{array}{l|l:l}F& 0 & 1\\ \hline 0& & \times \\ \hdashline 1 & \times & \end{array}$$

Answer (score 1):

> I have the intuition that I need a two element universe of discourse

Ok lets start with that.  Lets call those elements 1 and 2.

$$\exists x.\forall y.Fxy$$
$$\exists x.(Fx1 \text{ and } Fx2)$$
$$(F11 \text{ and } F12) \text { or } (F21 \text{ and } F22)$$

and for the second

$$\forall y.\exists x.Fxy$$
$$\forall y.(F1y \text{ or } F2y)$$
$$(F11 \text{ or } F21) \text{ and } (F12 \text{ or } F22)$$
and now distribute: apply $(x \text{ or } y) \text{ and } z$ is equivalent to $(x \text{ and } z) \text{ or } (y \text{ and } z)$:
$$(F11 \text{ and } F12) \text { or } (F11 \text{ and } F22) \text{ or } (F21 \text{ and } F12) \text { or } (F21 \text{ and } F22)$$

Can you see which is the stronger statement ?

Comment: Nice approach..

Comment: @GrahamKemp I was actually going to do the grid approach but then I saw it in your answer and didn't want to be repetitive, so I went with distribution instead.  If I was showing it in person I would have done the grid thing.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I have done these, but I think you could formulate the answer as so.

Fxy means that person y knows person x's name

Then the first expression means there is a person who everyone knows. The second expression means that all people are known by someone. These are not equivalent; one example is that the universe of discourse contains the people Alice, Bob, and Charlie. Bob and Charlie know Alice, but neither Alice nor Charlie know Bob (poor Bob!). Since these can both be true at the same time, and i is true while ii is false, i and ii are not logically equivalent.

The reason this was hard to get to (to my mind at least) was that the role of x and y are 'backward' in the function Fxy - Fxy means "y knows x" in order to make this work.

Comment: Thank you, that clears it up some but I have a follow up question; what is the extension of F in that interpretation? Would it have to be the same for both statements?

Comment: (Note that I just edited my answer to change the roles of x and y, does that resolve your question?) In my current answer at least, F _does_ have the same meaning in both i and ii.  Fxy means that y knows x.

Comment: I had saved my previous answer, and you're right - I did change the meaning of F going from i to ii. My bad ;) My current answer changed F slightly, and now it's possible to come up with an interpretation that makes i true and ii false. I allude to the switch in my current answer.

Answer (score 0):

In predicate logic, quantifiers ($\exists, \forall$), always implicitly quantify over the whole *universe* (that is your base set of values the variables can take).

If we name the universe $U$, then formula i. can also be written as:
$(\exists x\in U)(\forall y \in U) \big(F(x,y)\big)$

We can set $U$ to be an almost abitrary set - but for usual, you want to set $U$ to a set of natural numbers, e.g. $U = \{1,2\}$ for a two element universe.

To check your hunch, we only need to find all possibilities to define $F$, and pair each of those possibilities up with our universe and check.

$F$ is called a relation symbol or predicate symbol. It basically maps a tuple to a truth value by the following principle: 
If $F$ has the arity of $n$ (i.e. $F$ takes $n$ variables), then $F$ is a set of tuples $\\(x_1,...,x_n)$, and it's defined like this:

$F(x_1,...,x_n) = 
\begin{cases}
1, \text{ if } (x_1,...,x_n) \in F\\
0, \text{ else }
\end{cases}$

In our example, $F$ has the arity 2, and could therefore be defined as $F = \{(1,1),(2,1)\}$. Therefore, e.g. $F(1,1) = 1, F(1,2) = 0$.

In this example, both i. and ii. evaluate to $0$, so this particular version of $F$ doesn't solve the question. So we choose another version for $F$, and try again...

Answer (score 0):

Interpret $F(x,y)$ as '$x$ is the father of $y$'

Taking as the domain all people, the statements thus become:

$\exists x \forall y F(x,y)$: 'Someone is the father of everyone' -> False!

$\forall y \exists x F(x,y)$: 'Everyone has a father' -> True!